# iOS: how to change between views after picking a photos?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm writing an App that user can pick a photo in library, send to a server.
This is my code

```
-(IBAction)btnTakePictureClicked {
    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate=self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
    [picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.imgTemp = image;

// Where should these lines be?
    Send* send = [[Send alloc] initWithNibName:@"Send Email" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:send animated:YES];
    [send release];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I expected that after picking a photo, it will change to Send page. But, it still back to the home page.

Where should these lines be?

```
Send* send = [[Send alloc] initWithNibName:@"Send Email" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:send animated:YES];
    [send release];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you present an modal view controller with animation, release it in completed block, you can try:

```
    Send* send = [[Send alloc] initWithNibName:@"Send Email" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:send animated:YES completion:^{
        [send release];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you pick image it will move to send View controller

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
self.imgTemp = image;
Send* send = [[Send alloc] initWithNibName:@"Send Email" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:send animated:YES];
[send release];
```

}

Comment: It still back to the page with contains the button to load from library. Anyway, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
    [picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.imgTemp = image;
.....
```

here u make that YES to NO. ie., dismiss the modalview without animation.

Comment: I'm sorry Gomathi. That's not what I'm asking.